# How to send headers to an external API for authentication in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm a newbie trying to connect to my first API in Meteor.
The [API docs (linked here)](https://docs.wceaapi.org/v1.1/4_authentication) gave me a list of things I needed to generate (time-stamp, api-key & signature. I've generated them all and saved them as variables.) The docs say I need to make the following request:

```
curl -H "Request-Time: Wed, 06 Nov 2013 16:32:03 +0000" \
 -H "Api-Key: 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592" \
 -H "Signature: 42d8824f24fb50e6793aa111c889b7df4d54bee9f5842a0d5fbca30cbfa469ae" \
 http://wceaapi.org/v1.1/user/1234
```

How do I convert that in to Meteor Syntax?
Here's what I'm trying but I'm pretty sure it's totally wrong.

```js
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        callAPI: function () {
            this.unblock();
            return Meteor.http.call("GET", "http://sandbox.wceaapi.org",
                                    headers: {
                                        "Request-Time" : timeStamp,
                                        "Api-Key": key,
                                        "Signature": hash});
        }
    });
}

//invoke the server method
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.call("callAPI", function(error, results) {
        console.log(results.content); //results.data should be a JSON object
    });
}
```

Comment: i don't see anything wrong with that, other than some missing commas in the `headers` object (which I've fixed now).

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `http://wceaapi.org/v1.1/user/1234` as the url? Also the Meteor docs use `Http.call(...)` not `Meteor.http.call(...)`